# When to use "this" before "is" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Which way is correct?

> 1. While *this is* late breaking news, I want you to know that we are aware and looking into this intently.
> 2. While *is* late breaking news, I want you to know that we are aware and looking into this intently.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The second version is *completely* invalid. The assertion after ***while*** has to be a valid sentence in its own right - ***This is breaking news***. You can't just have the assertion ***Is breaking news*** with no syntactic subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your clause has a verb ("is") and an object ("news," modified to be the noun phrase "late-breaking news").

You must also have a subject.

The pronoun "this" is the subject of the clause. You cannot remove it. "While is late-breaking news" makes no grammatical sense.